# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha^{2})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Let $f = X^{4}+X^{3}-X+2 \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ and suppose that $f(\alpha)=0$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$.  Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha^{2})$.

So far i've tried to look at the structure of the groups:

$\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = \{b+c\alpha\}$

and (assuming that $\alpha^{2}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$)

$\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^{2}) = \{b+c\alpha^{2}\}$

it is easy to see that: $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^{2})\subset\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ but it's the other side:
$\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\subset\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^{2})$
 which bothers me.

any tips/tricks?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to *assume* that $\alpha^2$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, since algebraic numbers are closed under multiplication and $\alpha$ is algebraic.

Comment: didn't know that for sure, so thanks!

Comment: Do you really think $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)= \{a+b\alpha :a,b\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2)= \{a+b\alpha^2 :a,b\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ holds by definition of adjoining some element to $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: i do, a definition in my book tells me:

$\alpha$ is algebraic $\iff$ $K(\alpha)=K[\alpha]$

Comment: @KeesTil: and how do you define $K[\alpha]$?

Comment: $K[\alpha] = \{b+c\alpha \ \text{with} \ b,c \in K\}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}\newcommand{\a}{\alpha}$
As you say, it's clear that $\Q(\a^2) \subset \Q(\a)$, so you need to prove $\Q(\a) \subset \Q(\a^2)$. This is equivalent to $\a \in \Q(\a^2)$.

But you know that $\a^4 + \a^3 - \a + 2 = 0$. Equivalently, $(\a^2)^2 + \a (\a^2 - 1) + 2 = 0$. Besides neither $1$ nor $-1$ are roots of $f$, so $\a^2 \neq 1$. Therefore $$\a = \frac{2 + (\a^2)^2}{1-\a^2} \in \Q(\a^2)$$

Note that your description of $\Q(\a)$ and $\Q(\a^2)$ are a bit far off. They are respectively the minimal subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\a$, resp $\a^2$, so you need to consider all rational fractions (the ones that make sense that is, don't divide by 0). The description $\Q(\beta) = \{ b + c \beta \}$ is only valid in some cases, for example $\beta = \sqrt{2}$ (or more generally when it's a quadratic extension).

Comment: the reason i said that is because we know that:

If $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ and i personally think that writing this down without fractions looks a lot easier. But in this case it's better to just write down the definition.

Comment: What you say is true, but $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ may have polynomials of higher order than 1. For example $\mathbb{Q}[2^{1/3}] = \{ a + b 2^{1/3} + c 2^{2/3}\}$.

Comment: this is brilliant... I like your idea of writing down $\a^4 + \a^3 - \a + 2 = 0 \Rightarrow (\a^2)^2 + \a (\a^2 - 1) + 2 = 0 \Rightarrow \a = \frac{2 + (\a^2)^2}{1-\a^2} \in \Q(\a^2)$.. and you are so particular about completeness by making sure that $\a^2 \neq 1$.. very well written :)

Comment: i was thinking about this question later on the day, and wandered if we're able to construct a g(x) which is a minimal polynomial of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^{2})$ knowing the minimal polynomial of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$?